# Selenium and Backgroundworker -> driver.quit

Tags: c#, vb.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

im working on a project with selenium. I startet a webdriver via a backgroundworker. Then in the backgroundworker i used driver.quit to close the browser. But the browser wont quit. I've also used driver.dispose and driver.close. Is this a bug, or am i doing something wrong?

```vb
Private Sub BackgroundWorker_Test_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker_Test.DoWork
    
   Dim driver As IWebDriver = New ChromeDriver()
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("somesite")
   info = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[5]/footer/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]")).Text
   Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
   driver.Quit()
End Sub
```

It simply does not want to quit the browser and i am not getting any error in the debugger.

Many thanks.

Comment: It works on my side, did you called background worker:    `BackgroundWorker_Test.RunWorkerAsync()` ?

Comment: Yes and i solved the problem. I cant say why this problem occured and i dont know how i fixed it ;D